# How can I use the results of clustering algorithms for classification

Tags: classification, clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I'm doing a mobile customer segmentation and I was using K-means to cluster my data according to the various data points (location, time of use, duration used for etc). After reading a lot of posts in the last couple of days on CV, I know these clusters are more of a pattern discovery to be combined with business acumen rather than any 'group labeling' but it's a little hard to explain it to the end client whose expectation is that we should be ale to 'predict' which 'cluster' a new user belongs to. Any viewpoint as to if we can do that and if yes, how?

I know this might seem a little vague so trying to put it across

```
Dataset
Id Feature1 Feature2 Feature3
1       191     2999      910
2       902      516       39...

kmeans$centers

Cluster Feature1 Feature2 Feature3
     1       578      80       190
     2       167     7890      819
```

From this I can infer that my cluster #1 is with a group of users who are predominantly have Feature1 and cluster#2 might be a group which highly exhibit a combination of Feature2 and Feature3.

Now the discussion essentially boils down to if a user x comes with Feature1, Feature2 and Feature3, is there any way to figure out which cluster the user might belong to.

Comment: Is there any way to know later if your clustering was correct? For example, can you deduce from the customers purchasing behaviour if you put him in the right cluster or not? (The answer should be yes, otherwise, how are your clusters relevant?) You can use such post hoc information to compare the performance of different clusterings that are perhaps followed by classification to do induction. If that is not possible, you can still run a random index of similar validation measures in your clusters.

Comment: With k-means, a new point x can be assigned to a cluster by finding the cluster centroid closest to x